# Making a specific chart clickable in highcharts

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts, click

I have a lot of charts that get initialized in one function. It includes line, spline, bar and a scatter graph.

Now i want just the scatter graph to be clickable.

Whatever ways i searched till now make the clickable changes to all the charts.

How can i make only one particular chart clickable?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it would be easier to look into if you share the code

Comment: On the `chart.events.click` do a check for `this.options.chart.type`.

Answer (score 0):

can you please refer below link.

[Clickable scatter chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-click/)

we can get value on click as below :

```
 plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                events: {
                    click: function (event) {
                        alert(
                            this.name + ' clicked\n' +
                            'Alt: ' + event.altKey + '\n' +
                            'Control: ' + event.ctrlKey + '\n' +
                            'Meta: ' + event.metaKey + '\n' +
                            'Shift: ' + event.shiftKey
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```